# No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor, two method with same result but different output

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two request that will produce the same output. A `Iterable<Skill>` where `Skill` is an object with some properties (no other classes nested).

This gives me no error and work like a charm.

```
@GetMapping(path="/getAllSkills")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Skill> getAllSkills() {
    return skillRepository.getAllSkills();
}
```

This one is failing.

```
@PostMapping(path="/editSkill")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Skill> editSkill(@RequestBody EditSkillRequest body) {
    User u = userRepository.getUserBySessionToken(body.getSessionToken());
    Skill s = skillRepository.getById(body.getId());
       
    s.setCost(body.getCost());
    s.setName(body.getName());
    s.setDescription(body.getDescription());
    skillRepository.save(s);

    return skillRepository.getAllSkills();
}
```

I tried with `getAllSkills()` (self created query) and with `findAll()` too.
I get the same error

```
2021-09-09 23:19:14.373 ERROR 7452 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested excepti
on is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.Inv
alidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEA
NS) (through reference chain: WHLive.messages.EditSkillResponse["skills"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->WHLive.model.Skill$HibernateProxy$PvDfTPV7["hibernateLazyInitializer"])] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: WHLive.messages.EditSkillResponse["skills"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->WHLive.model.Skill$HibernateProxy$PvDfTPV7["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1514) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:454) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:4.0.FR]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_301]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_301]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_301]
```

EDIT: As requested

```
public class EditSkillRequest extends BaseRequest {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int cost;
    private boolean career;
    private boolean mastery;
    private boolean style;
    private boolean advanced;
    private boolean supreme;
    private String description;

    EditSkillRequest() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public boolean isCareer() {
        return career;
    }

    public void setCareer(boolean career) {
        this.career = career;
    }

    public boolean isMastery() {
        return mastery;
    }

    public void setMastery(boolean mastery) {
        this.mastery = mastery;
    }

    public boolean isStyle() {
        return style;
    }

    public void setStyle(boolean style) {
        this.style = style;
    }

    public boolean isAdvanced() {
        return advanced;
    }

    public void setAdvanced(boolean advanced) {
        this.advanced = advanced;
    }

    public boolean isSupreme() {
        return supreme;
    }

    public void setSupreme(boolean supreme) {
        this.supreme = supreme;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do `Skill` & `EditSkillRequest` objects contain getters for all fields?

Comment: @yoni yes they do. Some are isNameField insted of get, since they are boolean. But i don't think this is the issue

Comment: Can you please upload `EditSkillRequest` class here? is there a field named: `skills'?

Comment: no there is not, in the request i don't need a Skill. I have the id of the skill to edit and the fields that need to be edited.

Comment: Thx. Try use `findById` instead of `getById`. Maybe it's a mass because of the lazy loading and proxy of the DB.

Comment: I'm not using gtById for retrieving the list of Skills (the error is a the return statement), i'm using skillRepository.getAllSkills();

Comment: I meant it: `Skill s = skillRepository.getById(body.getId());`

Comment: Try skillRepository.flush() after save

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace `getById` with `findById`. The reason being that the first one is a lazy load operation and as a consequence you only get a reference (a proxy) to the entity. On the other hand, `findById` is a eagger load operation, and as a consequence, you immediately have the actual entity fully populated.

```java
@PostMapping(path="/editSkill")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<Skill> editSkill(@RequestBody EditSkillRequest body) {
    User u = userRepository.getUserBySessionToken(body.getSessionToken());
    Skill s = skillRepository.findByid(body.getId());
       
    s.setCost(body.getCost());
    s.setName(body.getName());
    s.setDescription(body.getDescription());
    skillRepository.save(s);

    return skillRepository.getAllSkills();
}
```